# Xml documentation not packed in class library

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I have two projects, MyModels (contains class models) and MyExample
The XML file is created in MyModels project, thats fine.

Now in MyExample project, I reference MyModels by installing it via nuget, but how do I include the XML document in the package when the nuget package is installed? (its always missing)

Comment: What project type is ist? do you use a csproj with integrated NuGet (VS 2017 "sdk-based" csproj) or nuspec to pack?

Comment: @001, Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Comment: I manually copied the XML file to the correct directory, because I couldnt get it to work. :(

Answer (score 3):

> Xml documentation not packed in class library

If you are in the common .csproj type project not "SDK-based", you can include the XML document directly to include in the package by using the `<files>` node in the `.nuspec` file, which follows the `<metadata>` tag:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.dll" target="lib\Net45" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.xml" target="lib\Net45" />
  </files>
```

Following is my `.nuspec`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyModels</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.dll" target="lib\Net45" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.xml" target="lib\Net45" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then [build the package with this command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#adding-a-readme-and-other-files):

```
nuget pack MyModels.nuspec
```

NuGet.exe successfully creates the nupkg:

[image]

If you are using the new .csproj type project (VS2017 SDK-based), you can set `GenerateDocumentationFile` into your csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

With the option `GenerateDocumentationFile`, MSBuild will include all the generate file in the nuget package.

Besides, if you want the XML document to the project of `MyExample`, you can change the target to the content:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.dll" target="lib\Net45" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.xml" target="Content\MyModels.xml" />
  </files>
```

Hope this helps.

**Update for comment:**

> I am using .NET Core 2, is it the same?

Yes, you just need update the src and target in the `.nuspec` file:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyModels.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyModels.xml" target="lib\netcoreapp2.0" />
  </files>
```

Or you can directly use the new `.csproj` type project (VS2017 SDK-based), set `GenerateDocumentationFile` into `.csproj` file, then check the checkbox "Generate NuGet Package on build" on the Package tab of properties of project:

[image]

After build, the nuget package generated at output folder:

[image]

Note: if you want add want the XML document to the project of MyExample, you should use content files:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#including-assembly-files

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your response leo, I am using .NET Core 2, is it the same?

Comment: @001, yes, you just need use `netcoreapp2.0` in the .nuspec file, for the details, please check my updated answer.